# Can benefit be used with the preposition with?

Tags: grammar

Can benefit be used the preposition WITH?

For example,

My participation in this program will benefit me with a head start on my medical education.

Is it consider grammatically correct? If not, why?

(I know it may sound awkward, but can it be written that way.)

I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: See no reason why not. There are other ways of saying it, such as *benefit me by providing a head start...*. But I see nothing wrong with what you have written.

Answer (score 2):

Far more idiomatic, I think, to say "give me the benefit of".  As a verb, *benefit* takes a direct object and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying. However you failed to answer my question. Do you know of any grammar rule stating it is incorrect?

Comment: It's not a grammatical rule, it's a semantic one.  In the absence of a specific idiom, an adverbial phrase beginning with _with_  means "accompanied by" ("eat with friends") or "through the use of" ("eat with your fingers").  What you seem to mean by "benefit with" doesn't fall into either category and there is no idiom for it.